# AutocompletePrediction/AutocompleteFilter with respect to current location

Tags: android, android-studio, google-places-api, autocompletefilter

I am using AutoComplete Place google API, but i am getting results outside my country or state. But i need results near to my current location.

Say I am in India, Chennai, if I type 'C' in AutoCompleteEditText, I ll get Central Park, New York, USA as my first result. But I need Chennai as in google map.

Please check the below img links for ur reference...

[What i need is this...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78GSI.png)

[But I am getting this..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRttJ.png)

Comment: read https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete about location — The point around which you wish to retrieve place information. Must be specified as latitude,longitude. Combine it with radius

Comment: I agree with @user3344236, but then add `components` parameter specifying the country, eg `components=country:in` for your scenario to restrict your results further. Looking it over, you might be able to simply use the `components` without specifying location and radius, but that should be found out easily through trial and error.

Comment: Seems https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete is for web service... is it possible to use with AutocompleteFilter